# Can't update dependency library when code was changed in npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, node-modules

I just started project react native. I created react native module by command `npm install react-native-my-library --save`, then run `npm install` I see it exist in node_module folder.

But when I change code in react native module, and remove folder node_module and run `npm install` again to update in node_module, it also doesn't update new code that I changed in native module.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Any body can help me to update code in node module folder.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Your problem description is rather difficult to understand, could you try to explain what the problem is in more detail?

Comment: @dentemm i have updated image for explain, please see my question again. thanks!